# TV Not Detecting Computer via HDMI, Need Restart Computer

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, tv

I have my desktop computer connected to my TV via a HDMI cable.  Being like this for the past two years without issues.

Recently, my TV is not detecting the computer and I'll need to restart my computer one or two time in order for the TV to detect the signal from the computer.  I know it's NOT the TV's issue because when I connect it to my laptop, it has not problem detecting the signal from the laptop.

OS: Windows 7
Computer Video: AMD Radeon HD 6500 Series
TV: Samsung PND8000

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how the error is occurring? For example, is the TV off when you boot the PC, and you occasionally receive the issue? Is the TV always on when you boot the PC? Is it occurring randomly while the PC is connected and both devices are on?